# C# WPF DataGrid. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter 'index'

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm learning to create a C# WPF Desktop Application. I wanted to retrieve the data from database and paste into the datagrid. I managed to retrieve some of the data and the error as title said appeared.

This is the XAML code for the datagrid.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="scenarioDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="53,40,53,10" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scenarioNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding scenarioNum}" Header="No." Width="50" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scenarioNameColumn" Binding="{Binding scenarioName}" Header="Scenario Name" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scenarioDateColumn" Binding="{Binding scenarioDate}" Header="Date" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

This is the scenario class I created

```
public class ScenarioData
        {
            public int scenarioNum { get; set; }
            public string? scenarioName { get; set; }
            public string? scenarioDate { get; set; }
        }
```

Then this is the code that I used to retrieve the data from database and paste it in the datagrid

```
                conn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT COUNT(scenarioID) OVER () AS 'Num', scenarioName AS 'Scenario Name', scenarioDate AS 'Scenario Date' FROM tbl_scenario";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

                if(dr.Read())
                {
                    int dataCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Num"].ToString());
                    List<ScenarioData> dataForDatagrid = new List<ScenarioData>();
                    
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dataForDatagrid.Add(new ScenarioData()
                        {
                            scenarioName = dr["Scenario Name"].ToString(),
                            scenarioDate = dr["Scenario Date"].ToString(),
                        });
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < dataCount; ++j)
                    {
                        scenarioDataGrid.Items.Add(new ScenarioData()
                        {
                            scenarioNum = j+1,
                            scenarioName = dataForDatagrid[j].scenarioName,
                            scenarioDate = dataForDatagrid[j].scenarioDate,
                        });
                    }
```

This is the database in SSMS [Database View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvV95.png)

This is what I got when running the code [Executed code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4et31.png)

Much appreciate if someone can point out which part I'm doing it wrongly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear why you create a `List<ScenarioData>` prior to populating the Items property of the DataGrid. This intermediate list seems totally redundant. Besides that, you should use `dataForDatagrid.Length` instead of `dataCount` in the for-loop. Their values might not be equal.

Comment: It would really help if you could include the complete exception stack trace in the question as text, rather than a screenshot of just the message, with no indication of exactly where it came from.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the whole for-loop and just assign `scenarioDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataForDatagrid;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because

1. the first `dr.Read()` is consuming the first record from the reader, so you are populating just the second and the third records to `dataForDatagrid`
2. `dataCount` value is 3, so inside the `for loop` you will be asking for `dataForDatagrid[2]`, which is not exist!

Moreover, you can get rid off the `dataCount` at all..

```cs
List<ScenarioData> dataForDatagrid = new List<ScenarioData>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    dataForDatagrid.Add(new ScenarioData()
    {
        scenarioName = dr["Scenario Name"].ToString(),
        scenarioDate = dr["Scenario Date"].ToString(),
    });
}

for (int j = 0; j < dataForDatagrid.Count ; ++j)
{
    scenarioDataGrid.Items.Add(new ScenarioData()
    {
        scenarioNum = j+1,
        scenarioName = dataForDatagrid[j].scenarioName,
        scenarioDate = dataForDatagrid[j].scenarioDate,
    });
}
```

Or you just get rid of the intermediate `dataForDatagrid` collection:

```
int j = 0;

while (dr.Read())
{
    scenarioDataGrid.Items.Add(new ScenarioData()
    {
        scenarioNum = ++j,
        scenarioName = dr["Scenario Name"].ToString(),
        scenarioDate = dr["Scenario Date"].ToString(),
    });
}
```

If for any reason you need the `dataForDatagrid` collection, do this:

```
List<ScenarioData> dataForDatagrid = new List<ScenarioData>();
int j = 0;

while (dr.Read())
{
    dataForDatagrid.Add(new ScenarioData()
    {
        scenarioNum = ++j,
        scenarioName = dr["Scenario Name"].ToString(),
        scenarioDate = dr["Scenario Date"].ToString(),
    });
}

scenarioDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataForDatagrid;
```